# MySQL query Foreign Key referencing Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, hierarchical-data

I have this table that is referencing itself.

[image: table]

Is there a way to show the parent name in a query? Something like `if (parent_id != null) {SHOW name WHERE id=parent_id} else {is_parent = TRUE)`. This is just how I see the logic.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have hierarchical or recursive functionality :/

Comment: @OMGPonies Can't it be done with `IF something THEN SET variable=name;` for example. Taken from the MySQL manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe simply:

```
SELECT U.*, UP.name
FROM units U
LEFT JOIN units UP ON U.parent_id = UP.id
```

?